# Array of objects or hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, class, sorting, hash

While working with a hash today in Ruby, I kept coming up against a few complications when sorting and accessing it. In my mind, I needed just a simple array.pop method to do what I needed. being that I just learned about class definitions, I had an idea and wanted to see if there was a reason not to do it this way.

```
hash = {"a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3}
```

Could I not do the same thing, but leave it open to more sorting methods and extensible data if I create this an array of objects containing data values?
Something like this

```
class Key
    attr_accessor :value
    def initialize (value)
        @value = value
    end
end
```

I'd then create an array of Key objects. I can then sort the array easier than the hash and still get the data from the inside the Keys. I figure this keeps things open for a more extensible bit of code if I find several bits of data need to be held together and sorted through.

Is this bad practice? Can you see a situation this would bite me? Am I solving a problem with a hammer because I just got one?

Comment: can you explain a bit more..what you want to do with your hash ?

Comment: I see three answers have been posted to a question that seems to require more information. to paraphrase @RahulSambari, what are you trying to do with your hash?

Comment: For this exercise, I was trying to sort by the value and then remove the highest value from the hash, destructively, returning that key - value pair into a variable. In an array, thats as simple as .pop method. Is there something similar to call on the hash?

Comment: I was also conducting a thought experiment. I was thinking about a data structure where I could call an object and return one of several pieces of data associated with that key. I know I can build an embedded hash with a hash of key-value pairs in the value place, but I was thinking about storing all these values within an object, which could allow for more readable code and I think some interesting options for building logic into a data structure. That said, I'm still very much a newb, so let me know if I'm liable to break everything.

Answer (score 1):

This ability is built into the Hash and Array data structures.

If you are using key-based access, get the keys and sort them:

```
hsh = {'a' => 1, 'c' => 3, 'b' => 2}

keys = hsh.keys.sort # keys: ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

If you need the values sorted, get the values and sort:

```
values = hsh.values.sort  # values: [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

`Hash` includes the `Enumerable` module which gives you all kinds of nifty ways of [enumerating and sorting](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html) the hash.

```
irb(main):006:0> h = {'a' => 1, 'c' => 3, 'b' => 2}
=> {"a"=>1, "c"=>3, "b"=>2}

irb(main):007:0> h.sort { |a,b| b<=> a }
=> [["c", 3], ["b", 2], ["a", 1]]

irb(main):010:0> h = { 'three' => 3, 'one' => 1, 'two' => 2 }
=> {"three"=>3, "one"=>1, "two"=>2}

irb(main):011:0> h.sort { |a,b| a[0] <=> b[0] }
=> [["one", 1], ["three", 3], ["two", 2]]

irb(main):012:0> h.sort { |a,b| a[1] <=> b[1] }
=> [["one", 1], ["two", 2], ["three", 3]]
```

If you are looking for an array of hash values based on some key sorting:

```
irb(main):016:0> h.keys.sort.map { |key| h[key] }
=> [1, 3, 2]
```